# MS Graph-Api on Windows Server 2016 in seperate AppDomain System.TypeLoadException

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

Just getting straight to the point and describe the Environment:

- On-Premise Windows 2016 Server (datacenter edition)
- All Frameworks (.net Core / .net 4.8 Full, etc) installed
- Windows-Service running plugins in seperate App-Domain (One by Plugin)

**Issue**

When loading the faulty plugin following Exception occures (Stripped because of german environment):

```
TypeName: "Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.Core.FindAllAccountsResult", Type: "System.TypeLoadException"
```

**Observations**

On every developers machine everything runs perfect.
On a Windows-Server 2019 it runs perfectly in the same setup. 
The file is present in %Windows%\System32-Folder

**What i tried**

- Compiled as x86 and x64 - No difference
- Added Nuget-references manually
- Installed Windows-10-sdk on Server
- Remote-Debugging without any more insights

**Conclusion**

Im still missing some components since everything works on Server 2019 
Also i cannot do an inplace-Upgrade, neither can i use a different server

See used references here

[image: References]

**Question**

What am i missing? Any help is highly welcome.

Comment: This question isn’t complete enough, what are you trying to accomplish? What code triggers the error?